# Generalization of divergence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So $\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot F = \int_{\partial \Omega} F \cdot n d\partial \Omega$

(Divergence Thm)

I was curious how this generalizes i.e

for a given real value test function $v$ on $\Omega$ i.e v is infinetly differentiable and $0$ on $\partial  \Omega$

$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot F)v = ?$

Or how would this work?

Comment: [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) using [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) is a generalisation of the divergence theorem and several other similar theorems/formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot F)v dx= \int_\Omega \sum_i v\partial_iF dx=\int_\Omega \sum_i [\partial_i(v F) -F\partial_iv] dx \\=\int_\Omega div(vF)  -\int_\Omega F\cdot\nabla v~ dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} Fv \cdot nd\sigma-\int_\Omega F\cdot\nabla v~ dx$$